# In Google Calendar, is there a way to open appointments in a new browser tab instead of in the same tab?

Tags: google-calendar

In Google Calendar, from the main calendar view, is there a way to have appointments open in a new browser tab when clicked, instead of opening in the same tab (the default behavior)?

Answer (score 1):

Not with the native interface. It looks like all of the data is already in the page and it's using JavaScript to change what is being displayed on the screen; it isn't opening a new page at all. It's not a classic link, so you can't right-click and choose different actions, for instance.